# Coroutine runs on a dispatcher even after its thread is shutdown

Tags: kotlin, threadpool, executorservice, kotlin-coroutines

I have a simple Kotlin program which creates an executor with a single thread and I use that as my coroutine dispatcher.

When I shut down my executor thread, i'm expecting the coroutine **not to run** (or **throw an exception**) since the **thread is terminated**, but that's not what's happening in the second method call to `runMethod(singleThread)`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val singleThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    runMethod(singleThread)
    singleThread.shutdownNow()
    runBlocking {
        delay(100)
    }
    println("Shutdown status: ${singleThread.isShutdown}, terminated status: ${singleThread.isTerminated}")
    runMethod(singleThread)

    println("Program ended")
}

fun runMethod(executor: ExecutorService) {
    runBlocking {
        launch(context = executor.asCoroutineDispatcher()) {
            for (i in 1..10) {
                print("$i ")
                delay(10)
            }
        }
    }
    println("\nEnd")
}
```

Here is the output for this program:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
End
Shutdown status: true, terminated status: true
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
End
Program ended

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess this might be a quirk of the fact that the only suspending function being used is `delay`. Since `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` is not a `ScheduledExecutorService` it has to rely on a fallback mechanism to dispatch the delay calls, which probably causes it to never actually use the provided `Executor` and always use the executor provided by `runBlocking` or `DefaultDelay` (the `delay` fallback).

To be sure inspect the `Thread.currentThread()` within the coroutine to see where the code is currently executing.

Comment: I think you're right, it looks like the second time it's running on the default executor: "kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor". Thank you for the response.